# Shorthand for inserting row into history table with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a trigger which copies a row whenever updated or deleted into a history table.

As of now I'm doing:

```
INSERT INTO history (column_x, column_y, column_z) VALUES (X, Y, Z);
```

Is it possible to shorthand it with:

```
INSERT INTO history VALUES (OLD)
```

The above does not work, but it gives an idea of what I'm looking for.
The columns match exactly as I've created the history table with:

```
CREATE TABLE history (LIKE original)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have some `primary key` defined in the table. Then you can do the `insert select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO history
SELECT * FROM notHistory WHERE ID = @ID
```